# Por que retorna TRUE e não FALSE?

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 0;
    var b = a == 0;

    function aoba() {
      document.getElementById('zbox').value = a;
      document.getElementById('ybox').value = b;
      a = a + 1;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="a" value="b" onclick="aoba()" name="botão">I'm gonna crazy.</button>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="zbox">
  </p>
  <input type="text" id="ybox">
</body>

</html>
```

Por que no campo `ybox` sempre aparece **true** quando deveria aparecer **false**?

Comment: Não devia aparecer false, está correto, quando você cria "b" o valor de "a" é zero, então o valor de "b" é true, e vc não altera o valor de "b" em nenhum lugar após isso.

Comment: Quando faz uma pergunta do tipo "deveria acontecer isso" explique porque acha que deveria acontecer. Você pode [edit] a pergunta.

Comment: Remova a imagem e coloque o código real para testarmos.

Comment: Pensei que toda vez que b fosse acessado ele obrigatoriamente verificaria a e atualizaria a condição de true ou false.

Answer (score 4):

Muito simples...

Você setou o valor de `a = 0;` e de `var b = a == 0;`. Neste momento **a** terá o valor de 0 e **b** terá o valor de true. O que mostra os primeiros valores nos `inputs`.

Após clicar no botão, você está atualizando o valor de **a** para `a + 1`. Porém, não está atualizando o valor de **b**, pois ao clicar no botão, ele chama a função `aoba()`, e é executado somente esse códig abaixo:

```
function aoba(){
    document.getElementById('zbox').value=a;
    document.getElementById('ybox').value=b;
    a = a+1;
}
```

Ou seja, em nenhum momento o valor da variável **b** está sendo atualizada.

Para atualizar o valor de **b**, coloque ele dentro da função `aoba()`, desta forma:

```
function aoba(){
    var b = a == 0;
    document.getElementById('zbox').value=a;
    document.getElementById('ybox').value=b;
    a = a+1;
}
```

Assim o valor de **b** será atualizado como deseja. O resultado pode ser visto no código abaixo:

```js
var a = 0;

function aoba(){
    var b = a == 0;
 document.getElementById('zbox').value=a;
 document.getElementById('ybox').value=b;
 a = a+1;
}
```

```html
<button id="a" value="b" onclick="aoba()" name="botão">I'm gonna crazy.</button>
<p>
 <input type="text" id="zbox">
</p> 
 <input type="text" id="ybox">
```

Aproveitando, [esta lista de perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20escopo) oferece um grande conteúdo a sua dúvida, direta ou indiretamente.

Comment: Agora entendi, muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu estava com uma dúvida relativa a um trecho de um script que estou criando, enquanto eu aguardava resposta acabei conseguindo driblar o problema com alguma criatividade, Não tenho nenhum curso na área, faço pra passar o tempo, desculpem-me se as vezes faço alguma pergunta tosca, colei abaixo a forma como eu driblei o problema.

Comment: /*excFormula*/if(det==0&&per==0&&rep==0){var excFormula=true}else{excFormula=false};
 /*otmFormula*/if((det == 0 && per == 1 && rep <= 1) || (det == 0 && per <= 2 && rep == 0) || (det == 0 && per == 0 && rep <= 2)){var otmFormula=true}else{otmFormula=false};
 /*bomFormula*/if((det == 0 && per <= 2 && rep == 0) || (det == 0 && per <= 1 && rep <= 2) || (det == 0 && per == 0 && rep <= 4)){var bomFormula=true}else{bomFormula=false};
 /*regFormula*/if(){var regFormula=true}else{regFormula=false};

Comment: @DanielDeSantanaSforzim O que importa é a forma que a pergunta é elaborada, e não se é uma dúvida "tosca" ou não. Sobre esse script que postou, tem como melhorar ele (nem sei se ele está funcionando adequadamente). Mas se quiser alguma dica, abra outra pergunta explicando melhor o que deseja, que ficará mais fácil ter ajuda.

Comment: Funciona sim,tem como deixar ele mais enxuto?

Comment: @DanielDeSantanaSforzim Tem sim, mas isso não é o assunto para essa pergunta. Pode abrir uma outra explicando o que deseja com o código e tal.

Comment: Obg!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Sete a variável "b" dentro da função para atualiza-la.